# Why is a StackOverflowError being thrown, when the code is in a try and catch statement?

Tags: java, api, exception, try-catch

I am trying to write an API for an interpreter for a language of my own creation, and I have three classes so far:

Here is a snippet from class 'CandleInterpreter' (The main API class):

```
protected Class<?> inputClass;
protected Class<?> outputClass;
public String input;
protected String currentFile;

public CandleInterpreter(Class<?> inputClass, Class<?> outputClass) {
    this.inputClass = inputClass;
    this.outputClass = outputClass;
    this.input = "";
    this.currentFile = "";
}
```

this class contains this method:

```
public void output(String message) {
    try {
        outputClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(message);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        output("Output class is invalid.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet from class 'Output':

```
public class Output {
    public Output(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet from class 'Main':

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CandleInterpreter interpreter = new CandleInterpreter(Input.class, Output.class);
    interpreter.output("Hello World!");
}
```

This code works fine, but in the main class, when I pass a different class into the 'CandleInterpreter' object, instead of the 'Output.class' class, a 'StackOverflowError' is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.lang.StringUTF16.compress(StringUTF16.java:158)
at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:3002)
at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:250)
at java.base/java.util.StringJoiner.toString(StringJoiner.java:187)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.methodToString(Class.java:3374)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3302)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2110)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:107)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
at CandleAPI.CandleInterpreter.output(CandleInterpreter.java:109)
...
```

I am confused why this error is being thrown, as I have the line of code 'outputClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(message);' in a try and catch statement. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

-PrimeCubed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is throwing the exception :

```
     output("Output class is invalid.");
```

Hence code goes into catch block and tries to execute :

```
       output("Output class is invalid.");
```

Instead if you replace your code in catch block to below, it will not get into infinite loop:

```
        System.out.println("Output class is invalid.);
```

Answer (score 2):

A StackOverflowError is an Error, not an Exception. Catching `Exception` will not catch a `StackOverflowError`.

You *can* catch it - either as `StackOverflowError`, `Error` or `Throwable` - but what do think you can achieve by doing so? `Error`s are meant to be unrecoverable conditions.

Comment: Ah I see! I didn't know there was a difference between those three types. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't read your code carefully, but StackOverflowError is an error not an exception.

```
StackOverflowError extends VirtualMachineError

VirtualMachineError extends Error

Error extends Throwable
```

Show in this case, you can try cat a Throwable instead.
For root cause, you should look at you call stack and figure it out how can it be stack overflow.